# Why it doesn't reset the code after the user asks to restart the program?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

So this is my code. Upgraded. I had some issues with the While loops but I ve managed to get over it.
Now my problem is this.
When the user gets at the end of the loop and is being asked to play again the program won t change its random number. Any help would be really appreciated.
And as the title says, python won t recognize capital Y and N and it will only take y and n.

```
from random import *
def play():
    return guess()

def retry():
    while True:
        replay = input("Try again ?(Y/N)")
        if replay not in {"y", "n"}:
            print("Please enter Yes or No")
        elif replay.lower() == "n":
            print("Thanks for playing! Bye now!.")
            break
        elif replay.lower() == "y":
            print("As you wish!")
            return guess()

def guess():
    while True:
        user = int(input("Guess the number: \n"))
        print(user,a)
        if user < a:
            print("Higher")
        elif user > a:
            print("Lower")
        if user == a:
            return retry()
a = randint(0,20)



play()
```

Comment: Think about what `if replay not in {"y", "n"}:` does. Compare it to the other two conditions. What's different?

Comment: If you have a new question, then _**post a new question**_. Please do not edit the original question and change it to a different one, because that would invalidate any comments and any existing answers. I reverted your edits and rollbacked to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't reset `a` because it was never instructed to do so. When you restart the game, you should generate a new number:

```
...
        elif replay.lower() == "y":
            print("As you wish!")

            # Tell the interpreter that we want to modify a variable from the global scope
            global a

            # Generate a new random number
            a = randint(0,20)

            return guess()

...
```

> And as the title says, python won t recognize capital Y and N and it will only take y and n

You should change the following line:

```
        replay = input("Try again ?(Y/N)")
```

To:

```
        replay = input("Try again ?(Y/N)").lower()
```

Otherwise your following condition will fail, because `Y` and `N` are not in `{"y", "n"}`. Though, the brackets doesn't really make sense here, and would be better to simply do:

```
if replay not in "yn":
```

**EDIT:** Instead of validating the answer twice, just look for valid answers and then ask for a valid one if it wasn't provided:

```
replay = input("Try again ?(Y/N)").lower()
if replay == 'y':
    # replay...
elif replay = 'n'
    print("Thanks for playing! Bye now!.")
    break
else:
    print("Please enter Yes or No")
```

**EDIT:** To ensure the given input is a valid number, you could use a `try/except` block to catch the error:

```
try:
    user = int(input("Guess the number: \n"))
except ValueError:
    print('Not a valid number.')
```

Or you could ensure the given string is a number using `str.isdigit`:

```
user = input("Guess the number: \n")
if user.isdigit():
    user = int(user)
else:
    print('Not a valid number.')
```

I would personally go with the `try/except` since the second is basically validating the string twice (once through `isdigit`, then another when the `int` cast is done).

Comment: First half is good, second part is nonsense. You can't assign to a function call.

Comment: `You can't assign to a function call.` Nice catch! Obviously added the `.lower()` to the wrong end. Fixed, thanks for spotting it.

Comment: Nice work. The braces are to make a set, which probably doesn't help when you have two items, but is faster in the general case.

Comment: Yea. The first part solved my problem and now i get random numbers every time. And for the second part i have done this:  
``` while True:
        replay = input("Try again ?(Y/N)")
        if replay not in {"y", "n","Y","N"}:
            print("Please enter Yes or No")
        elif replay.lower() == "n" or replay.lower() == "N":```
And it is working. Not the best way to do it but it works. 
So any feedback is really appreciated

Comment: I think you are making it complicated. There is no reason to validate the answer twice (once through `in`, then another through the conditions) and it could be simplified with an `if, elif, else` block. Edited my answer to provide an example.

Comment: This bit ``` if replay not in "yn": ``` works just fine but the rest of it doesn't really work. I still have to add the lower n/y by myself otherwise it will loop the question forever. 
And I have one more question. If i want to do something similar to the ```if replay not in ``` but for the numbers part. How could I do that? Basically if the user input is different than a number it will print a message.

Comment: `I still have to add the lower n/y by myself otherwise it will loop the question forever.` Sounds like you didn't add the `.lower()` to your `input()` call.

Comment: I ve corrected the code. It works fine now the way you said. 
I still need some help if you could tell me how to display an error message(print) when the user gives the wrong input for numbers.
Also how does this work: if replay not in "yn": ? Does  it not need to have a comma in between?

Comment: I don't understand? You already print `Higher` or `Lower` when the number is not the right one, can't you just edit these messages?

Comment: Sorry.  What I meant is that when the user is asked to guess a number and lets say by mistake you press A instead of a number. The program will just throw an error. What can i do to print a text when that happens.?

Comment: The first method works. Just need to arrange my code properly now. Thanks very much!